# Why collections sort Method cannot be used on set interface

Tags: java, sorting, set

Sorry for the bad subject,just wanted to know,
Why cant we implement sort method on set any specific reasons?

Answer (score 3):

Set is meant to have no order, says the math theory. Not saying that anything forbids a sorted set, but the purpose here is to represent math set concept as is.

However, there also exists a sorted set interface: [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you just take an arbitrary Java `Set`, there is no API that allows you to modify the order of the set.  The `Set` interface has no methods for modifying order.

Comment: That's true, but the question is why not.

Comment: ...because if you did, then the interface you're looking at would be `List`?  Also because many of the useful `Set` implementations couldn't support it efficiently?

Comment: See, now THAT's an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to, you could write a collection class that implemented the `Set` interface, but had an underlying order like a `List`.  That would be something that you could sort.

I'm not sure why you'd ever do such a thing; and as far as I know, there is no such class in the JDK or any of the commonly used libraries.  I just don't see what the point of such a class would be.  If  you want something to remember an order, use a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method can not be applied on the Set instance and even Set Interface itself doesn't have any sort() method on it, unlike List Interface.
It's because when we normally add the value in any Set Instance so it follows the concept of generation of hashcode and assigning the elements based on their hashcode for better performance and for no duplicacy.

Set numberSet = new HashSet<>();

```
    numberSet.add(10);
    numberSet.add(100);
    numberSet.add(11);
    numberSet.add(1111);
    numberSet.add(121);
```

now numberSet will add these values based on their hashcodes and retrieval of values will also be done based on the same prinicple.

Let's say if somehow we have a sort method on Set, then let's say we have sorted the set and values get arranged according to the ordering context which we want.
Then the values will be rearranged in the Set Data Structure (means now the contract which is being shared by Set that all the objects which have the same hashcode will be saved at a particular position that will get broken because of reordering and now the Set no longer can perform the operations in O(1) and can't check for duplicacy too according to it's underlying implementation ).

If you want to hold the Set sorted values there is a way:

We can open up a stream and then call sort() or sort(Comparator(? extends T)) can call any of the methods after opening the stream.

For calling these methods your class should implement Comparable Interface

1. sorted() -> internally uses compareTo method.
2. sorted(Comparator) -> uses your comparator lambda

Stream stream = numberSet.stream().sorted((obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getRollNumber() - obj2.getRollNumber());

now, these sort methods will return the sorted values in a Stream which is sorted.

But if you try to do stream..collect(Collectors.toSet());
try to collect the values in the set again and think now the set holds the sorted values. Set will not hold values in a sorted manner as it will hold the values in the set adding contract manner (using hashcode generation and all that again, values will be added in the same order as it was earlier).